# Optimizing a System of 5 Equations

Tags: mathematical-optimization, system

I have a system of 5 equations that each define a parameter for a metal I-beam. The common variables are beam width (W), web thickness (Tw), and flange thickness (Tf). I would like to find the best values for the three variables that defines the best beam based on the following requirements:

```
1.5 <= FS (yield strength) <= 2.0

-70 in <= ytotal <= 70 in

Price<= $600, 000.00

42, 000 hrs <= Flt Hrs

Weight<= 78, 000 lb
```

With weight being the priority to minimize, and price being a secondary priority.

The equations:

```
fS[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 73000/(471960000/Abs[1/12 (34 - 2 tf) tw^3 + (tf ww^3)/6] + 
    17 Abs[(101163822 - (1257 weight[ww, tw, tf])/2)/((9826 ww)/3 - 
         1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))])

weight[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 126.957 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf ww)

life[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 3.12508*10^26/((1/(1 - 
          0.000366932 Abs[(101163822 - 
               79792.5 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf ww))/((9826 ww)/3 - 
               1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))]))^7 *
     Abs[(101163822 - 
          79792.5 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf*ww))/((9826 ww)/3 - 
          1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))]^7)

price[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 1213.71 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf ww)

ytotal[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 76997298573639/(72500000 ((9826 ww)/3 - 
       1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))) - (3045.37 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 
       2 tf ww))/((9826 ww)/3 - 1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

EDIT: Updated YTotal as per Bob's recommendation. The functions are defined as their outputs, and the background algebra that leads to the functions is too extensive to post here. Edit: Removed my FindInstance work.

EDIT: Updated the code with Daniel's formatted code. As Daniel pointed out, I did not define boundaries for the parameters. Here they are:

```
22<=w<=38
tw>=.1w
tf>=3.4
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Include the statements that define your functions (e.g., FS, Weight, Life, Price, Ytotal). It is bad practice to use capital letters as the first letter of user-defined variables, functions, and constants. This can cause naming conflicts with built-in Mathematica names. In your output for `FS[W, Tw, Tf]` and `Ytotal[W, Tw, Tf]`, `Weight` appears without its arguments.

Comment: Please post your definitions in a way that enables direct evaluation. Have a look at the site to see how this usually works.

Comment: What should happen in that `Life` function when the first fellow under the power of 6.99301 goes negative? At that point one has complex values.

Comment: Also what might be plausible minimal values for the three parameters? Such values would be important to have for any optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this could have been formatted in a more usable manner. Also there are conventions about avoiding capitalizing, and sometimes I like to avoid single letter "variables" other than e.g. loop indices.

I will remark that an early attempt at optimizing ran me afoul of real arithmetic (see comment regarding fractional exponent and negative base values). So I simply altered it to the nearest integer, that is, 6.993 becomes 7 in the code below. Also it is often useful to make complicated functions like these only defined for explicitly numeric input. That has the advantage of forcing optimization code to avoid possibly complicated symbolic preprocessing.

With the above considerations in mind, here is a reformatted version of the functions at hand.

```
fS[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 73000/(471960000/Abs[1/12 (34 - 2 tf) tw^3 + (tf ww^3)/6] + 
    17 Abs[(101163822 - (1257 weight[ww, tw, tf])/2)/((9826 ww)/3 - 
         1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))])

weight[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 126.957 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf ww)

life[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 3.12508*10^26/((1/(1 - 
          0.000366932 Abs[(101163822 - 
               79792.5 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf ww))/((9826 ww)/3 - 
               1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))]))^7 *
     Abs[(101163822 - 
          79792.5 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf*ww))/((9826 ww)/3 - 
          1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))]^7)

price[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 1213.71 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 2 tf ww)

ytotal[ww_?NumberQ, tw_?NumberQ, tf_?NumberQ] := 
 76997298573639/(72500000 ((9826 ww)/3 - 
       1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))) - (3045.37 ((34 - 2 tf) tw + 
       2 tf ww))/((9826 ww)/3 - 1/12 (34 - 2 tf)^3 (-tw + ww))
```

There were two different versions of constraints in the post. Below I use the first one and also add some minimum values for the three physical parameters. I do not know if my values are plausible but I can say that some values will be needed and it is preferable that they be explicit constants with weak inequalities rather than e.g. `tw>0`.

```
constraints = {1.5 <= fS[ww, tw, tf] <= 2, 
   78000 >= weight[ww, tw, tf], 48000 <= life[ww, tw, tf], 
   600000 >= price[ww, tw, tf], -70 <= ytotal[ww, tw, tf] <= 70, 
   ww > 1, tw > 1, tf > 1};
```

I tried a few settings for the optimization. The one below gave a perhaps plausible result. For the objective function I simply weighted `price` and `weight`. (I mean, how often does one get to "weight weight"?)

```
{min, vals} = 
 NMinimize[{weight[ww, tw, tf] + price[ww, tw, tf]/10, 
   constraints}, {ww, tw, tf}, 
  Method -> {"RandomSearch", "PostProcess" -> "InteriorPoint"}, 
  MaxIterations -> 200]

During evaluation of In[108]:= NMinimize::incst: NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {1.5 -fS[ww,tw,tf]<=0,-2+fS[ww,tw,tf]<=0,48000-life[ww,tw,tf]<=0,-600000+price[ww,tw,tf]<=0,-78000+weight[ww,tw,tf]<=0,-70-ytotal[ww,tw,tf]<=0,-70+ytotal[ww,tw,tf]<=0}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution. >>

(* Out[108]= {115536.111738, {ww -> 25.5149248202, tw -> 3.37881625946, 
  tf -> 7.91413553622}} *)
```

We check the various function values. Not sure if it is okay for `ytotal` to be negative. The others seem okay.

```
{fS[ww, tw, tf], weight[ww, tw, tf], life[ww, tw, tf], 
  price[ww, tw, tf], ytotal[ww, tw, tf]} /. vals

(* Out[109]= {1.99999999996, 59067.5160991, 48000.0000002, \
564685.956384, -4.89435760154} *)
```

Any lack of quality in the result, or problems with the method, should serve to emphasize some points made herein and in comments: it is crucial that one have a full example of a problem, in order to show a viable approach. Even details like "Which set of constraints do I use?" or "How does one handle complex values that might appear?" will cause needless head-scratching and in general act as deterrents to useful responses.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response, this is exactly the type of method I was looking for! I went ahead and added the parameter boundaries to the original post for conclusivity sake.